# Python unknown encoding utf8

Tags: python-2.7, lets-encrypt

I need to renew my Letsencrypt certificate, but python doesn't find UTF8 encoding.

[image]

Comment: 1. Please include the traceback **as text**, not a screenshot. 2. If you don't have access to `utf-8` there is probably something wrong with your Python installation, try reinstalling it.

Comment: How do I reinstall python ? Ubuntu 14 won't allow me.

Comment: If you're using the system Python that might be tricky. Maybe ask at [ubuntu.se]

Answer (score 0):

If your LANG variable is not UTF-8 just change it temporarily:

```
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
export LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8
```

And try again.